# Print missing elements that lie in range 0 – 99

Tags: javascript

I wrote code in JavaScript but issues with start value ex: ?-9, ?-87...etc

```
Input: {88, 105, 3, 2, 200, 0, 10}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function RangeValues(){
    var a = [88, 105, 3, 2, 200, 0, 10];
    var n = a.length;
    var pq = [];
    for(var i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        if(a[i] >= 0 && a[i] <= 99)
            pq.push(a[i]);
    }
    var start = 0;
    if(!Array.prototype.last) {
        Array.prototype.last = function() {
            return this[this.length - 1];
        }
    }
    while(pq.length != 0)
    {
        var num = pq.last();
        pq.pop();
        if(num - start > 1){
            console.log( (start) +','+ (num-1));
        }
        if((num - start) == 1)
        {
            start = num + 1;
            console.log(start);
        }
    }
    if(start == 99){
        console.log('99');
    }
    else if(start < 100) {
        console.log(start+' to '+99);
    }
    return 0;
}

RangeValues();

</script>
```

```
actual output: 0-9,0-1,0-2,0-87,0-99
Expected: 1,4-9,11-87,89-99
```

Comment: This code is working right. What is your purpose here? give more detail about your expectation.

Comment: Input: {88, 105, 3, 2, 200, 0, 10}, **Output expected: 1,4-9,11-87,89-99**. But actually coming out out is : 0-9,0-1,0-2,0-87,0-99.

Comment: another example Input : [50, 1, 2, 0,72, 52] , Expected output: 3-49,51,53- 74,76-99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should sort number in array `pq` descending so the last value is the min number. Try with below solution:

```js
function RangeValues(){
var a = [88, 105, 3, 2, 200, 0, 10];
//var a = [12, 105, 23, 1, 200, 4, 21];
var n = a.length;
var pq = [];
for(var i = 0; i<n; i++) {
  if(a[i] >= 0 && a[i] <= 99){
    pq.push(a[i]);
  }
}
// sort array descending 
pq.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});

var start = 0;
if(!Array.prototype.last) {
  Array.prototype.last = function() {
    return this[this.length - 1];
  }
}
while(pq.length != 0){
  var num = pq.last();
  pq.pop();
  
  if (num-start == 2 || num == 1){
    console.log(num-1);
  } else if((num - start)>2){
    var from = start + 1;
    var end  = num - 1;
    console.log(from+" - "+end);
  }
  start = num;
}
if (start < 98){
  var from = start + 1;
  console.log(from+" - "+99);
} else if( start == 98){
  console.log(start+1);
}
 
  return 0;
}
RangeValues();
```

Comment: Yes.. expected but **need format also like 1,4-9,11-87,89-99**

Comment: I have give you a suggestion! the remain thing I think it's not hard! Try yourself. SO is not place that we code for you.

Comment: @vasanth naidu, I have update my answer as you expected, please check it.

Comment: Yes.. Thanks...Exected...:)